# How to keep Android app running and quit Unity Activity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-lifecycle

I'm developing an app that integrates with Unity3d, in some part of my code I call an UnityPlayerActivity that starts the Unity3d code. When user finishes using the Unity3d he press a button and go back to Android code. 
My problem is when I go back to android code, after UnityPlayerActivity calls:

```
@Override protected void onDestroy ()
{
    mUnityPlayer.quit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

The application is closed, not only the Unity Activity. I could not call this method, but I think that would be wasting memory.

Is there any way I could quit only Unity3d activity and keep my application running normally so I could start Unity3d part again another time?

Tks

Comment: You could start unity activity in a new thread, and then kill that thread when work is done

Comment: I do not understand your question.Please elaborate do you want to return back to android Activity from your unity3d game???

Comment: Lipian, it´s an android project that has an small Unity game inside, I want to play that game and go back to my android project.

Comment: Ayush, how could I do that?

Comment: @user2494863 did you find any solution?

Answer (score 12):

Found an answer. Just need to use another process on manifest.

Basically means, you have to explicitly name your `Activity` process in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For instance.

```xml
<activity
   android:name=".UnityPreviewActivity"
   android:process=".UnityPreviewActivity" />
```

**Reference**

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/587979/how-do-i-stop-munityplayerquit-closing-the-entire.html

Comment: Although this answer was not chosen as the correct answer or had any +1, it works and solved the problem I had for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

**1.override kill() method  of UnityPlayer class**

class MyUnityPlayer extends UnityPlayer {

```
    public MyUnityPlayer(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void kill() {

    }
}
```

kill() is invoked in mUnityPlayer.quit() and it will kill current process:

```
protected void kill() {
        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    }
```

So override it to avoid process being killed.

**2.change the type of mUnityPlayer to MyUnityPlayer in UnityPlayerActivity**

**3.call finish() method of UnityPlayerActivity when you want to exit the Activity.**
(In my case,App crashed after fininshing UnityPlayerActivity  after starting a new activity from UnityPlayerActivity.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to override for some weird reason.

Comment: This works fine but the problem when doing this is when trying to start the unity activity AGAIN (after closing it), it crashes with a SIGSEGV Null Pointer Dereference. This doesn't happen if I don't override the kill method.

Comment: Same thing for me - second time opening the Unity Experience will result in a crash

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use reflection and therefore avoid calling the kill() method (which is called in quit()) which kills the current process

i.e.

```
   try {
        //1
        Field v = unityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredField("v");
        v.setAccessible(true);
        Method a = v.getType().getMethod("a");
        a.invoke(v.get(unityPlayer));

        //2
        Field o = unityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredField("o");
        o.setAccessible(true);
        o.set(unityPlayer, true);

        //3
        unityPlayer.pause();
        Method unloadVR = unityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("unloadGoogleVR");
        unloadVR.setAccessible(true);
        unloadVR.invoke(unityPlayer);

        //4
        unityPlayer.removeAllViews();

        //5
        Method h = unityPlayer.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("h");
        h.setAccessible(true);
        h.invoke(unityPlayer);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This works fine but the problem when doing this is when trying to start the unity activity AGAIN (after closing it), it crashes with a SIGSEGV Null Pointer Dereference.